# How to run airodump-ng as a background task?

Tags: linux, background-process, airodump-ng

I'm interested in running airodump-ng as a background task, since I only need the exported results and don't need to interact with it.

However, the following operation doesn't work:

airodump-ng wlan0 &

I tried digging into the code but the only solution I see would be to remove all output operations, which seems not efficient and overkill at the same time. Would you folk have a better way to achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally was able to run airodump-ng in background by using tmux the following way:

```
tmux new -d -> creates a new tmux window in background 
tmux send -Rt 0 airodump-ng SPACE wlan0 ENTER  -> sends the given keys to the backgound terminal
```

This way, airodump-ng works and doesn't take 100% CPU like with screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can use screen to run command in background while still preserving it's output. Use something like

```
screen -d -m airodump-ng wlan0
```

You can later re-attach to the screen by running:

```
screen -r
```

and stop your command or do whatever else you need to do.

If you have more than one screens active, you can use `screen -ls` to list them all and then pass PID of the one you want to resume as an argument to `screen -r` command.

Comment: This is clever, thanks ! I'm not flagging it as an answer rightaway though, since I suppose it adds a bit overhead to the execution :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with airodump, so, I wen't with screen as universal and quick fix. It's possible airodump supports running in background, so, if anyone offers that solution, you should definitely accept it.

Comment: Looks like the "little overhead" is in fact a 100% load on my cpu, any idea why ?

Comment: No idea, check `top` for culprit. Is it screen or airodump or something else?

Comment: It is screen, but it only jappens with airodump-ng

Comment: Does CPU usage remains high even after you re-attach to the running screen session?

Comment: Yes it does, although at a lesser extent (drops to 60% instead of 100%)

Comment: Sounds like some unusual interaction between screen and airodump. With no environment to play with, I'm afraid I cannot be of much more assistance.

Comment: I'll fig a bit and edit your answer if I find the problem

Answer (score 0):

There is a hidden option that informs airodump-ng to run in a background. The interactive thread will not be started:

```
airodump-ng -K 1 wlan0
```

information found here: https://forum.aircrack-ng.org/index.php?topic=648.0

This should fix the high CPU usage bug.